# Change the statistics while making an API request

Tags: javascript, api

I am using the following API to make a request and display some statistics about the liverpool team on my website.

```
    var request = new XMLHttpRequest()

    request.open('GET', 'https://www.thesportsdb.com/api/v1/json/1/searchteams.php?t=liverpool', true)

    request.onload = function() {
      Begin accessing JSON data here
        var data = JSON.parse(this.response);
        var team = data.teams[0].strTeam;
        var league = data.teams[0].strLeague;
        var stadium = data.teams[0].strStadium;
        var info = data.teams[0].strStadiumDescription;
        var teamBadge = data.teams[0].strTeamBadge;
        var teamJersey = data.teams[0].strTeamJersey;

    document.getElementById("demo").innerHTML = team ;
    document.getElementById("demo2").innerHTML = league ;
    document.getElementById("demo3").innerHTML = stadium ;
    document.getElementById("demo4").innerHTML = info ;
    document.getElementById("demo5").src = teamBadge;
    document.getElementById("demo6").src = teamJersey;
```

I want to make a dropdown on my website so I can choose another team and it automatically displays the statistics of the new chosen team. Currently I just manually change the name in the API request string, eg - liverpool to Burnley to display the burnley statistics

Answer (score 0):

You can have a dropdown with a handler like this. You're listening for the `onchange` event and passing the updated `select` object to the function `onTeamChange`. Then you can get the value that the user changed to and use that to construct your GET request.

```
function onTeamChange(teamList) {
  const selectedTeam = teamList.value;
  console.log(selectedTeam);

  // Call existing code here and modify url:
  const teamUrl = `https://www.thesportsdb.com/api/v1/json/1/searchteams.php?t=${selectedTeam}`;
}

<select id="team-selector" onchange="onTeamChange(this)">
  <option value="liverpool">Liverpool</option>
  <option value="burnley">Burnley</option>
  <option value="arsenal">Best Team Ever</option>
</select>
```